# Is there a website that can show the best deals for roundtrip flights separated by a certain number of days?

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, airlines, flight-search-engines

I am looking for a website or application that knows how to show results for the following scenario:

Suppose i want to travel from city A to city B by airplane. While i don't impose a specific date for the departure, i want it to be somewhere in summer, between June 1st and September 1st. What i do know is the duration of my visit, which is about 10 days.

I'd like to input this data and have the website return me a list of roundtrip flights (ordered by best prices) within this period, which are 10 days apart - bonus if i can even specify +/- 1/2 days if a better deal is available.

Does anyone know of such a website? The closest i could find matching my requirements is SkyScanner, but it still doesn't provide me the level of specification i need as described above.

Comment: United's website provides this functionality but not for every possible duration.  Since it only searches United and partner flights it's not really an answer, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean like [image]

this? Use http://matrix.itasoftware.com/ for any advanced needs.

Comment: Yes, this is the closest to what i'm looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

www.adioso.com will allow you to enter a date range and the length of the trip.

Comment: Thanks, this is also a very good option, however chx's suggested website seems to show more flight possibilities than Adioso.